# Present But Cannot Be Compiled

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, configure

I'm getting the following warnings when trying to run `./configure` on OSX Mavericks with Xcode 5.1.1 and Command Line Tools installed:

```
checking pcre.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: pcre.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: pcre.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: pcre.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: pcre.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: pcre.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for pcre.h... no
```

The same message is coming up for other header files as well... `time.h`, `sys/time.h`, `syslog.h`, etc.

Any clue how this can be fixed?

Comment: I would start by looking at the configure.log (or is it config.log) to see what is being complained about...

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in config.log as twalberg suggested:

> configure:14647: gcc -c -g -O2 -Wextra -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -fno-tree-pre -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu99 -DOS_DARWIN -DIPFW  -I/opt/local/include conftest.c >&5
>    **clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-tree-pre'**

I chose to force my project to use llvm-gcc for greater compatibility with older projects:

> CC=llvm-gcc ./configure

You could also edit "configure.ac" and remove "-fno-tree-pcre" from the CFLAGS, but you may hit other compatibility problems further down the line. Good luck!

> --- configure.ac.orig  2014-09-24 16:16:11.000000000 -0700
>   +++ configure.ac.works 2014-09-24 16:19:29.000000000 -0700
>   @@ -65,7 +65,7 @@
>                   CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wextra -Werror-implicit-function-declaration"
>                   # remove optimization options that break our code
>                   # VJ 2010/06/27: no-tree-pre added. It breaks ringbuffers code.
>   -                CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fno-tree-pre"
>   +                CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
>           else
>                   CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -W"
>           fi

Comment: Ran into similar issues with a different flag that was no longer supported in recent versions of gcc (mine: v6.1.0).  Turns out -Wunused-but-set-variable got folded into -Wall, so you can just use that.  Looking into -fno-pre-tree, it looks like this is folded into -O2 now, so you should get the optimization you seek by just using that optimization level...with relatively recent versions of gcc.  clang flags are not always compatible with gcc, so suggest using -O2 in that case as well.